# Bat files not running under spesific script on exec function

Tags: php

please help because iam new on PHP and i build good system here but still final step to run my batch files i will try to enplane what is my problem :
The Bat files generated with PHP successfully with following results : 
.Bat file output is :

**START "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2017\3dsmaxcmd.exe" -submit:manager-servername -gammaCorrection:1 -gammaValueIn:0 -gammaValueOut:2.1 -w:800 -h:600 -jobName:filename.max -split:10,1 -outputName=T:\ss.bmp -rfw=true L:\filename.max.bat**

this bat file whats doing after 40 hours of tests : 
1- start CMD automatically 
2- execute 3dsmaxcmd - program - which is the command line for autodesk software 
3- inject parameters specially designed for 3dsmaxcmd.exe
4- output export to final destination path 
+++++++
Notes : 
PHP self installed in windows server not hosted with full access and permissions- php ver is 7.7.2

so when i execute it with double click in windows its executed but in PHP nothing happens i try many methods like \ instead of \ path and "" or ''  - and please note i cant change the order in bat file like deleting START i need it execute under exec like as is . what can i do - waiting experts answers please .

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Your question is not clear.

Comment: that is runs bat files and the bat runs the software 3d and the command line for the 3d software complete rendering and do his job automatically - so what i need from PHP is after user submit his file and generate bat - these are done by PHP ok still that execute bat by one click submission button -let me know about any thing not clear

Comment: by other word - my question is - how to run bat file contains the commands above ?